# jquery validation ajax and remote field unexpected behavior

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I've been struggling with this all day. I need to validate a form and if valid submit it using an ajax call. From what I've read the submitHandler should fire once all validation has occurred, including remote checks.

When I enter a UserName that  already exists I get the `'User Name already exists'` message and the submitHandler is not called, as expected. But if any other validation check fails, the form gets posted normally to the form action url, and the submitHandler callback never seems to get called.

Hopefully someone can see what I'm doing wrong:

```
<form id="addUserForm">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead class="text-warning">
            <tr>
                <th>User Name</th>
                <th>Password</th>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Email Address</th>
                <th>User Type</th>
                <th class="center">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" value="" name="username" id="Name" class="span12">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="password" value="" name="password" id="Password" class="span12">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" value="" name="forename" id="FirstName" class="span12">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" value="" name="surname" id="LastName" class="span12">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" value="" name="email" id="Email" class="span12">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select name="Type" class="span12" id="Type">
                                <option>Administrator</option>
                                <option selected="selected">Standard</option>
                                <option>Surveyor</option>

                    </select>
                </td>
                <td class="center">
                    <button class="btn" id="btnAdd">Add</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#addUserForm').validate({
            onsubmit: true, onfocusout: false, onkeyup: false, onclick: false, errorPlacement: function (error, element) { },
            invalidHandler: function (event, validator) {
                if (validator.errorList.length) {
                    alert(validator.errorList[0].message);
                    validator.errorList[0].element.focus();
                }
            },
            rules: {
                username: { required: true, remote: '/admin/isusernameavailable' },
                password: { required: true },
                forename: { required: true },
                surname: { required: true },
                email: { required: true, email: true }
            },
            messages: {
                username: { required: 'User Name is required', remote: 'User Name already exists' },
                password: { required: 'Password is required' },
                forename: { required: 'First Name is required' },
                surname: { required: 'Last Name is required' },
                email: { required: 'Email Address is required', email: 'Email Address is invalid' }
            },
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                // create the data object
                var data = {
                    Name: $('#Name').val(),
                    Password: $('#Password').val(),
                    FirstName: $('#FirstName').val(),
                    LastName: $('#LastName').val(),
                    Email: $('#Email').val(),
                    Type: $('#Type').val()
                }

                // post the form
                var posting = $.post('/admin/adduser', data);

                // post success
                posting.done(function (data) {

                    // display the results
                    $('#results').html(data);

                    $('#Name').val('');
                    $('#Password').val('');
                    $('#FirstName').val('');
                    $('#LastName').val('');
                    $('#Email').val('');
                    $('#Type').val('Standard');
                });

                // post error
                posting.fail(HandlePostFailError);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `onsubmit: true` option because that's the default behavior.

**Important**:  [as per docs](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate),

> `onsubmit`
> Validate the form on submit. Set to false to use only other events for validation. Set to a Function to decide for yourself when to run validation. **A boolean true is not a valid value.**

In other words, you must remove that line because `true` will break the plugin.

---

**Quote OP**:

> *"When I enter a UserName that already exists I get the 'User Name already exists' message and the `submitHandler` is not called, as
>   expected. But if any other validation check fails, the form gets
>   posted normally to the form action url, and the submitHandler callback
>   never seems to get called."*

The form is not supposed to post if there are outstanding errors, and the `submitHandler` is not supposed to fire after a validation error.  The `submitHandler` callback function only fires *when the form is valid*...

> `submitHandler` (default: native form submit)
>  Type: Function()
>   Callback for handling the actual submit **when the form is valid**.
>   Gets the form as the only argument. Replaces the default submit. The
>   right place to submit a form via Ajax after it is validated.

See:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate

---

**Tip**:

If you want to get rid of the plugin's error placement functionality, it's probably not a good idea to simply leave the function empty.  Place a `return false` inside the callback function instead.

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Sparky. I've removed `onsubmit:true;`, I've also added `return false;` to the errorPlacement function, but I'm still getting the form posting. Doing a bit more testing, it seems the posting occurs as soon as the username is valid. Could it be something to do with the remote rule?